# django - preventing from two clients to login as the same user

Tags: android, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I have a login/logout module in my django app (using DRF).

it works in token authentication - when user logs in he passes a username and a password and gets a token, that can be used forever.

(I save the token in my client app).
when he logs out - I delete the token from the client app.

The problem I noticed is that when one client **(android app)** in logged in with **user1** for example (currently has the token that was achieved from the server), other clients **can** login as the same user (provide same username and password and get the token) - and now I have both clients logged in as **user1**.

**Here is the django code for getting the token:**

```
class ObtainAuthTokenAndUser(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'user': user_serializer.data})

obtain_auth_token_and_user = ObtainAuthTokenAndUser.as_view()
```

**What can I do in order to prevent this situation??**

In the case of another client tries to log in with a already logged in user - I want to send a "already logged in from another device" message and a 401 HTTP.

Any ideas about how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if any valid token is already present in the database for the same user.

```
token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

instead of above method you should use

```
try:
    token = Token.objects.get(user=user) // Chcck if token is present
except Token.DoesNotExist:
    token = Token.objects.create(user=user) // Create new token, no token for this user
else:
    return Response({'error': 'Already logged in', status=400})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the thing is I create the tokens when users register, so the tokens are already exist in the database

Comment: In that case you can delete the token from server side when a user logs out. So that will mean token will be present for logged in users only. 
Now if you request for a new token you will get it if the token is already not in database for that user.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I ended up checking it in some other way which worked. thanks anyway :)